# expressJS request object

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I'm trying to go through the [expressJS tutorial](http://expressjs.com/guide.html). This is my server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express').createServer();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/', function(request, response) {
    console.log('Inside the post request!');
    console.log(request);
    response.send(resquest.body);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

and here is the POST request I am simulating:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000',
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: {hello: 1},
    success: function () {
        console.log('Success!');
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log('Error!');
    }
});
```

The problem is that the `request` object does not seem to contain `data: {hello: 1}`. Instead it is a big mess of under-the-hood parameters. Am I doing something stupid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written `resquest.body` instead of `request.body`; when you fix that, you'll be able to use `request.body.data` as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

I think that since you're not setting the [content type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) to multipart/form-data it's assuming form encoded data. In which case, you'd set your data in your ajax request to be:

```
data: 'hello=1'
```

Set your content-type to: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Access it via request.body.hello. It's been awhile, but try that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at `request.body`.  When you do `request.body`, you get `{hello: 1}`.

Comment: `request.body` is underfined for me

Comment: How?  I copied and pasted your code and replaced `console.log(request)` with `console.log(request.body)`, and that's what I got...  I used curl though: `curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"hello": 1}'  http://localhost:3000/`